# UIScrollView: More accurate/precise contentOffset value?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I was wondering if there is any way to get a more accurate version of the `contentOffset`, or estimate/calculate the `contentOffset` or (preferably) the first derivative of `contentOffset` of a `UIScrollView`. I am trying to perform an action when the rate of change of the `contentOffset` of my `UIScrollView` is very small, but 0.5f isn't quite precise enough.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get better precision than the one provided by `contentOffset`. You could calculate velocity using regular `ds/dt` equation:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    static CGFloat prevPos = 0.0; //you can store those in iVars
    static NSTimeInterval prevTime = 0.0;

    CGFloat newPos = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    NSTimeInterval newTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    double v = (newPos - prevPos)/(newTime - prevTime);

    prevPos = newPos;
    prevTime = newTime;
}
```

However, if you are feeling extremely hacky, and you want you code to be **unsafe**, you can peek into `UIScrollView`'s velocity iVars directly by using this category

```
@interface UIScrollView(UnsafeVelocity)
- (double) unsafeVerticalVelocty;
@end

@implementation UIScrollView(UnsafeVelocity)

- (double) unsafeVerticalVelocty
{
    double returnValue = 0.0;
    id verticalVel = nil;

    @try {
        verticalVel = [self valueForKey:@"_verticalVelocity"];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"KVC peek failed!");
    }
    @finally {
        if ([verticalVel isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            returnValue = [verticalVel doubleValue];
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}

@end
```

To get horizontal velocity replace `_verticalVelocity` with `_horizontalVelocity`. Notice, that the values you will get seem to be scaled differently. I repeat once more: while this is (probably) the best value of velocity you can get, it is very fragile and not future-proof.

Comment: Okay. I figured there weren't any safe ways to get a more precise value, but your answer seems to cover absolutely everything that anyone could need from this question. Thanks a lot! I'm going to try out the velocity iVars just for fun, though.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but what exactly do you do with the velocity to get a precise content offset?  It seems like any calculation you'd make would get you back to the same unprecise values.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The author was trying to get more precise `contentOffset` readings to calculate the *velocity*, so my answer simply cut the middleman od `contentOffset` altogether